# Twilio listing of all active clients

Tags: php, rest, twilio, twilio-php

My application needs to list all active/connected clients from the [Twilio Client](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client)-service through the REST API. I can't seem to find the documentation for it, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There's no direct way to list your currently connected/active Clients in the API.

If you are looking for control over agents within your system so that you can dynamically assign calls and tasks to available agents, then I suggest you take a look at the [TaskRouter API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The functionality is/were needed for livecalculating forecasts in a set of decentralized call centers, and also for detecting and kicking inactive clients to stop billing for someone not using the software :-).